# SOQL: Accessing the Contact Owner Field

Tags: salesforce, soql

I'm trying to write a SOQL query that will grab one of the Contact object's standard fields "Contact Owner", which is a Lookup(User) field:

[image]

The field name is "Owner", but when I try to query

SELECT Contact.Owner FROM Contact

I get an error stating that there is no such field.

```
SELECT Contact.Owner, Contact.Name, Contact.Rule_Class__c
       ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:8
No such column 'Owner' on entity 'Contact'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

How can I grab this field?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a normal behavior for Relation fields

[image]

You can imagine `OwnerId` as an alias

```apex
SELECT LastModifiedBy.Name,  LastModifiedBy.Id, LastModifiedById FROM Contact 

SELECT CreatedBy.Name,  CreatedBy.Id, CreatedById FROM Contact
```

Also use [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/) or Developer console or Eclipse to construct your queries instead of using salesforce setup interface

**Workbench**
[image]

**Developer Console**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is strange:

> "Select c.Owner.Email, c.Owner.Name, c.Owner.Username, c.OwnerId From
>   Contact c Run the above in Developer Console--Query Editor"

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&dc=General_Development&criteria=OPENQUESTIONS&id=906F0000000AvMHIA0

I wonder why Contact.Owner comes up as non-existent but Contact.Owner.Name is?